# How to create instance methods as property using setattr?

Tags: python

My goal is to create a class that allows that each instance can have unique attributes as properties. This attributes has to be created "dynamically" at the moment that the instance is created depending on the files that exist on an specific folder.

The idea is if inside a certain path I have the csv files 'foo.csv', 'boo.csv', the instance should be able to create the attributes ._foo and ._boo as None when it is initialize. And just after, also during the initialization, should create the methods foo and boo as property only for that instance.

So far I created the following File class that solve most of the goal.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

class Files(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.create_attributes_methods()

    def create_attributes_methods(self):
        for attr in self.files_in_directory:
            setattr(self, '_' + attr, None)
            setattr(self.__class__, attr, property(fget=self.attrgetter('_' + attr)))

    @staticmethod
    def attrgetter(attr):
        def get_any(self):
            if getattr(self, attr) is None:
                df = pd.read_csv(self.path+attr[1:]+'.csv')
                setattr(self, attr, df)

            return getattr(self, attr)

        return get_any

    @property
    def files_in_directory(self):
        csv_files_path = glob.glob(self.path + '/*.csv')
        return [elem.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0] for elem in csv_files_path]
    
folder = Files(r'mypath/')
folder.foo #First time read the csv file, store the DataFrame in folder._foo and return the DataFrame
folder.foo #Due that the variable folder._foo is not None, it will just return the DataFrame this time
```

However, the problem of this solution is that `setattr(self.__class__, attr, property(fget=self.attrgetter('_' + attr)))` creates the method for the class, and not for the instance. I have tried several alternatives related with `types.MethodType` in order to created bound methods, but I can't connect that approach to define the method as property. How to create instance methods (or bound methods) as property using setattr?

Comment: Descriptors (that is what `property` objects are and how they work) *must* belong to the class, they will not work as instance attributes, that is, the descriptor protocol will not be invoked

Comment: Note, this is true for methods as well. Function objects are just descriptors who's `__get__` method partially applies the instance to the method, and this *only* works when the function is in the class namespace, not the instance namespace. Instance methods *belong to the class*. EDIT: Some worthwhile reading: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know that descriptors had to belong to a class. I will read the shared source :).  Do you know how I could achieve the intended behaviour considering that relationship between descriptor and class?  Maybe definition of a nested class during the initialization?